# seek() after readline() working incorrectly in jython

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython, cpython, jython-2.7

I have a log file with some very long lines. I am using a mix of read() and readline() to read the file. I am seeing weird behavior when using Jython 2.7 while CPython2.7 works correctly. Following is a sample code the recreates my problem.

```
file = open("test.log", "w")
file.write("."*100 + "\n" + "."*4100 + "\n" + "."*100)
file.close()

file = open ("test.log")
data = file.read(4096)
data = file.readline()
print "Current fd position:    "+str(file.tell())
seek_back=4100
print "seeking back:           "+str(seek_back)
data = file.seek(-seek_back, 1)
print "fd position after seek: "+str(file.tell())
```

The fd position on the last line is 102 for CPython and 202 for Jython. Am I using seek/read in an incorrect way? Or is there a different problem?

Comment: try changing file = open("test.log", "w") to open("test.log", "wb"), and "rb"

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, check that Java is not writing to the file using UTF-16.

Comment: @Claris added the "wb" and "rb", didn't help. How would UTF-16 thing matter?

Comment: Java defaults to 2 byte characters (UTF-16), so would be writing twice as many bytes.

Comment: If I replace `open("test.log")` with `io.open("test.log", "rb")` in your example then it works as expected. Looks like a bug to me...

Comment: @mata, how can you use io with jython?

Comment: @user593644, might be related http://bugs.jython.org/issue1793

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - this is taged jython-2.7 - which does have the `io` module.

Comment: @mata, ah ok, I did not realise there was a final version of 2.7 released

Comment: Same issue for me using 2.5.3 so it must be an old bug

Comment: Thanks @mata, io is working as expected.But, our software needs to be backward compatible to cpython 2.4 as well and io was introduced in 2.6. I will need to figure out a different way if it is indeed a bug.